# Azure DevOps - when publishing the junit xml how do publish back into Azure DevOps the results in the form of a test run associated to a testcase

Tags: java, junit, azure-devops

In Azure Cloud we have pipelines which will be executing our junit 5 tests.  In Azure Dev Ops we have a test plan with a test suite with a test case configuration assigned to it.  With in the test suite, there are test cases and then we execute it in a run is my understanding.  Right now we are using the display name or test case name to map our junit test case to a azure test case id and have a customize html report. Is there a way to either push the junit xml test results back into Azure Dev Ops and associate the run with a test case or test suite via an API or some other plugin we need in the pipeline?

I have looked at some of the API's Azure Dev Ops have published and it seems unclear to me whether we can do above?

Or perhaps maybe we could create the test plan from scratch and some how associate the test case or runs to the test suite?